# Unable to resolve InitializeComponent in colors.xaml.cs and styles.xaml.cs

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I'm trying to create a MAUI project from my existing forms project, and as part of it I created two resources files, one for colors and the other for styles, but it says that it cannot find the InitializeComponent method in it, I've tried cleaning bin, obj, restarting VS, creating new Resource files, but it is still giving the error

Any inputs would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Usually, resources and styles are defined in *.xaml files without *.xaml.cs. Can you try adding a new ResourcesDictionary file and define your resources or styles there?

A ResourceDictionary file should look like this:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SampleApp">

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: This is working fine, but I had to create a xaml.cs to create an object out of it so that I can access it in on of my controls in code behind

Comment: Then just removing the InitializeComponent() might fix you problem.